# Javascript, In a self-calling recusrive function which iterates through tree branches, how to record each branch Level?

Tags: javascript

Lets see if I can explain this math problem... :)

Data tree may look like this, each pipe represents a branch:

```
Level
1           |
2     |  |  |  |  |  |   
3    ||        |     |||
4     |       |||
5
6
etc
```

I am iterating through each branch and need to record each branch's level. For example in the picture above we have 6 branches at level 3 and I need to mark each of these 6  as such being at level 3.

We have the following `TreeFunction()` which gets data from a remote server( via AJAX-ish calls), one branch level at a time.

`TreeFunction()` has a child `childFunction()` which will then store the current branch level data and proceed to call its father-Function(`TreeFunction()`) again and again until there is no more branches in the data-structure ( an external tree-like data structure ).

Code example below:

Each time `childFunction()` runs it will use the variable `branchLevel` to store the current branch level into the `tree_branches_object`.  The mechanics of storing this work fine.

The problem is I can't figure out how to calculate what the correct current `branchLevel` level is at each iteration/run of `childFunction()`.

The sample code below would have worked just fine had the data structure been one where each level had only one branch, hence each iteration of `TreeFunction()` would have marked the correct level via the `branchLevel++` statement.

But the data structure is one with multiple depth levels and multiple sibling/adjacent branches at each depth level. All adjacent branches should be reported at the same level even if each individual branch follows its own unique path in the tree.

```
//A local Object with one element/item for each branch 
  var tree_branches_object = [
        { "branch_level": branchLevel, "BirdsOnBranch": moderate },
        { "branch_level": branchLevel, "BirdsOnBranch": low },
        { "branch_level": branchLevel, "BirdsOnBranch": low },
   ]

//recursive Function 
function TreeFunction() {



//some test variable: Branch Level is set to 1
branchLevel = 1;

// obtain branch-info data from a server via AJAX-ish call 


var childFunction = function () {



    //Check for other branches 
    if (there_are_other_branches_in_the_tree) {

        // ?!? increase the branch level ?!?
        branchLevel++;

        // store the current branchLevel into the tree_branches_object object 
       tree_branches_object.push({ "branch_level": branchLevel, "BirdsOnBranch": low });

        // call TreeFunction again and obtain information for the next branch, until all branches in the three have been vizited.     

    }

}
```

}

Comment: pass in the current branch level plus one as an argument to the recursive function - then in the recursive function, use the passed in argument as the current branch level

Comment: [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)

Comment: Try not to do this with nested "child" and "father" functions. Don't use a global `branchLevel` variable, but instead pass everything you need between functions explicitly.

Comment: It seems I have been able to solve it with the help of your comments. It seems to work, when you define the current level in a variable inside of the ChildFunction and then pass that variable/level back to to the TreeFunction. I can post the whole thing if people are interested...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you started - there is lot of logic to "dump" the output, but the level calculation is fairly simple stuff.

```js
// Node object itself
function node(children) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(children) !== "[object Array]")
    throw new Error("children is not an array");
  this.children = children;
  for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
  {
    this.children[i].index = i;
  }
  
  var that = this;
  this.dump = function() {
    var levels = {};
    that.level = 0;
    that.nodeid = "0";
    var stack = [that];
    while(stack.length > 0)
    {
      var node = stack.pop();
      var key = node.level.toString();
      if (typeof levels[key]  === "undefined") {
        levels[key] = [];
      }
      levels[key].push(node);
      for(var i = node.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        node.children[i].level = node.level + 1;
        node.children[i].nodeid = node.nodeid + "." + node.children[i].index.toString();
        stack.push(node.children[i]);
      }
    }
    
    result = "";
    var i = 0;
    while(typeof levels[i.toString()] !== "undefined")
    {
      var level = levels[i.toString()];
      for(var j = 0; j < level.length; j++)
      {
        result += level[j].nodeid + ','
      }
      result += "\r\n";
      i++;
    }
      
    return result;
  }
}

// Test (based on your example):
var root = new node([ 
  new node([new node([]), new node([new node([])])]),
  new node([]),
  new node([]),
  new node([new node([new node([]), new node([]), new node([])])]),
  new node([]),
  new node([new node([]), new node([]), new node([])])
]);

console.log(root.dump());
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/svejdo1/9gw85d9h/7/

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I will look at it later.